# how do I post values from jquery to php

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, forms

trying to find out how I can take the value of the input form as modified by JQuery and submit it through a POST form into PHP for submission into a MySQL database.

here is the form:

```
`<fieldset>
                    <input type="date" name="paydate"> <br>
                    <input type="text" class="income" name="openingbalance" placeholder="Opening Balance"> <br>
                    <input type="text" class="income" name="income_1" placeholder="Cheques"> <br>
                    <input type="text" class="income" name="income_2" placeholder="Direct Deposit"> <br><br>
                        <label>Income</label><input type="text" class="sum" id="income_sum" name="Totalincome"><br>
                        <label>Expense</label><input type="text" class="sum" id="expense_sum" name="expense_sum" disabled><br>
                        <label>Remainder</label><input type="text" id="remainder" name="TotalRemainder"><br>
                </fieldset>`
```

and here is the script:

```
var $form = $('#balancesheet'),
        $summinc = $form.find('.income'),
        $summexp = $form.find('.expense'),
        $summrem = $form.find('.sum'),
        $sumDisplayIncome = $('#income_sum'),
        $sumDisplayExpense = $('#expense_sum'),
        $sumDisplayRemainder = $('#remainder');

    $form.keyup('.income', function ()
    {
        var sumIncome = 0;
        $summinc.each(function ()
        {
            var value = Number($(this).val());
            if (!isNaN(value)) sumIncome += value;
        });

        $('#income_sum').val(sumIncome);
    });

    $form.keyup('.expense', function ()
    {
        var sumExpense = 0;
        $summexp.each(function ()
        {
            var value = Number($(this).val());
            if (!isNaN(value)) sumExpense -= value;
        });
        $sumDisplayExpense.val(sumExpense);
    });

    $form.keyup('.sum', function()
    {
        var sumRemain = 0;
        $summrem.each(function ()
        {
            var value = Number($(this).val());
            if (!isNaN(value)) sumRemain += value;
        });
        $sumDisplayRemainder.val(sumRemain);
    });`
```

so the line: `<label>Remainder</label><input type="text" id="remainder" name="TotalRemainder">`
is one of two fields that I want to take the value of, as it is shown in JQuery and use it to POST to the php code and enter into the MySQL database

Thank you,

Comment: should check your syntax for `keyup`

Comment: tank you for the syntax comment, it actually works great already (unless that is by fluke)

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to do an asynchronous POST, you can use jquery's ajax function.

```
var form = $('#balancesheet');

$.ajax({

  url: 'your-file.php',
  data: form.serialize(),
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json', // assumes the php file will return json
  success: function(response){

    // do something with the response
  },
  error: function(xhr){
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
  }
});
```

If you just want to submit one field, you could call the ajax function the same way, but you would change:

```
data: form.serialize()
```

to something like

```
data: {remainder: $('#remainder').val()}
```

Your php needs to communicate it's success in adding the data to the db, and it's common practice to use [json](http://www.json.org/) as the communication protocol. Check out [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) if you're not already familiar with it.

Comment: thank you very much.  for now I have the math that I'm looking for complete inside of the php script that runs because I couldn't get this working.  I'm still very very new to the whole world of java/js/jquery etc.  but thank you very much for the response, I greatly appreciate it, and like to learn more... hopefully I will be able to understand what your ajax code really does and be able to use it in the near future